# How to JSF redirect after few seconds

Tags: jsf

I have one method on JSF Managed Bean, i want after user call method, and it do some business logic ,after that it will redirect some 2 seconds after some business logic complete. When business logic complete on 9:30:20 after that 9:30:22 page will redirect. How can i do on JSF Managed Bean?

Thank You!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not possible to control the client from the server side on. Your best bet is to handle it entirely at the client side. The most straightforward approach would be using a meta refresh header in the HTML `<head>` of the result page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=newpage.jsf" />
```

The above instructs the client to refresh the page after `2` seconds with the URL `newpage.jsf`.

Comment: oh, i think it can do but can't :D Thank you BalusC :D